# animations in AngularJS (changing colors)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I created some sort of checklist using CSS.
I want to, that if i click on a circle, it changes its color.

What I have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="steps">
    <i class="my-icon">
      <i class="circle1" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">1</i>
      <i class="circle2" nng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">2</i>
      <i class="circle3" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">3</i>
      <i class="circle4" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">4</i>
      <i class="circle5" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">7</i>
      <i class="circle6" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">6</i>
      <i class="circle7" ng-click="style={'background-color':'blue'}">5</i>
    </i>
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
    <div class="line4"></div>
    <div class="line5"></div>
    <div class="line6"></div>
    <div class="arc"> </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-icon {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
.my-icon > i {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 0.15789473684210525em solid #259B24;
    border-radius: 25em;
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
}
.my-icon > i+i {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 0.15789473684210525em solid #259B24;
    border-radius: 25em;
    left: 150px;
    top: 30px;
}

...
```

On the controller side, I haven't done much. I also want to save the changes after leaving the application, but i don't know where to start.

**JS**

```
.controller('rencontreController', function ($scope){

    });
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use ngStorage for persisting data.What range of colors are you planning to include.

Comment: I want the circle to be all green

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below
Use ngClass to set the class dynamically.
Use https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage to persist your Object.

In your HTML

```
<i class="circle1" ng-click="storedObj.one=true;save()" ng-class="{greenColor:storedObj.one}" >1</i>
<i class="circle2" ng-click="storedObj.two=true;save()" ng-class="{greenColor:storedObj.two}" >1</i>
```

In your JS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);
```

In your Controller you can do something like this

```
.controller('rencontreController', function ($scope,localStorageService){

if(localStorageService.get("storedObj").length>0){
 // If the local/session storage already has the object.
    $scope.storedObj=localStorageService.get("storedObj");          
}
else{    
// Initially, store the object in local/session Storage. 
  var obj = { 
             "one":false,
             "two":false
             //and many more
            }

  localStorageService.set("storedObj",obj);
  $scope.storedObj=localStorageService.get("storedObj");
}

$scope.save=function(){

    localStorageService.set("storedObj",$scope.storedObj); // This will make the selections persists even when the application closes

}
});
```

In your Css

```
.greenColor{
  background:green; // Or anything that you want to make your circle appear green
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. The thing is I want to click on the circle to change its color. It s not fixed to green

Comment: @Hana [Some Tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also do you mean that every time the user clicks;the color should change?

Comment: I already fix that like this : <i class="circle1" ng-style="myStyle1" ng-click="myStyle1={'background-color':'green'}">1</i> Now the problem is how to persist this information when the color changes

Comment: You can see the [ngStyle](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-style.asp) example. You can construct different objects (or different object properties) for different circle like [that](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-style.asp) and persist it as shown in my answer above using [Angular Local Storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)